# CLR vs Runtime vs Host

Tags: c#, clr, runtime

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaf1h1h5(v=VS.90).aspx it says:

In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the CLR provides hosting management interfaces to control many features of the hosted runtime, enables the host application to implement other management interfaces provided by the runtime, and lets you implement your own hosting management interfaces.

For purposes of discovery, the management interfaces fall into two broad categories:

`Management interfaces that the`**host**`implements and the`**runtime**`discovers through the IHostControl interface.`

`Management interfaces that the`**CLR**`provides and the host discovers through the ICLRControl interface.`

Can you pls explain what these bold words are?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CLR** is the *[Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)*, the environment under which all the dotnet applications run.
**Host** (in this context) is the unmanged application which hosts the CLR under it so that managed code can be run in its context (for eg. SQL Server, IIS etc). [The parent page of the link provided by you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) explains this.

"Runtime" rerers to CLR.

**Update**
Have a look at [this MSDNMag article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) for a detailed overview of CLR hosting APIs

Comment: The 2nd para on parent page says: **The runtime host loads the runtime into a process.** does it mean that unmanaged code (runtime host) loads CLR (runtime) into a process (as another process, child of unmanaged code's process).

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx . It says *"By using the hosting APIs, developers of native hosts can execute managed code in-process with complete knowledge and control over how the CLR behavior can affect their application"*

Comment: Let me go through all the links. if in doubt shall raise another query.